# textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте. 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня при инитиализации приложения создается DocumentListener, который отвечает за подсветку синтаксика, но после того как я загружаю другой документ с помощью:

```
private void readInFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        FileReader r = new FileReader(fileName);
        textArea.read(r,null);
        r.close();
        currentFile = fileName;
        frame.setTitle(currentFile);
        changed = false;
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, "Editor can't find the file called "+fileName);
    }
}
```

Подсветка работать перестает.
Попробовал вынести создание в отдельный метод:

```
    private void setDocumentListener() {
            textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
             //Здесь код
        }
    }
```

Прописал вызов в инитиализацию и в метод readInFile чтоб он вызывался повторно при загрузке нового документа, но это не сработало. Он так же работает только до первой загрузки нового документа.
Подскажите в чем может быть причина и что я не так делаю?

Comment: а как и когда вы вызываете `setDocumentListener`?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Mikhail Vaysman за комментарий, этот вопрос навел меня на ответ.
Я вызывал setDocumentListener() в самом методе readInFile() и он не работал, а после того как добавил его в метод где вызывался readInFile(), все прекрасно заработало. Вопрос закрыт.